# I want to suspend the numbering of my equations temporarily

Tags: equations, numbering, labels

Hopefully someone can help me with this. Essentially, I would like to suspend the numbering of my equations temporarily, as the title of the question suggests. For example:

(1)

(2)

(3)

```
  (1)

  (2)

  (3)
```

(4)

(5)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Which equation environment do you use? `equation`, `align`? It rather looks like you do a restart of equation numbers

Comment: I'm using align and sometimes align* for when I don't want numbering (i.e., during derivations)

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking.

Comment: It was clear enough to obtain an answer. But thanks for your input! :)

Comment: @user3125347: Yes, but it would have been nice to know **why** you need such behaviour of suspending? I think, there might be better ways than what I've proposed

Comment: It would have been nice, but some things are best left to the imagination! Thank you :)

Comment: @user3125347 So, as in your example, you want two or more equations with the same numbering? What is the interest of these numbering?

Comment: I want it temporarily suspended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll confuse your readers, probably. Anyway, you can use `subequations` that already provides the necessary infrastructure.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newenvironment{suspendequations}
 {\begin{subequations}\renewcommand\theequation{\arabic{equation}}}
 {\end{subequations}\addtocounter{equation}{-1}}



\begin{document}
A set of equations
\begin{gather}
1\\
2\\
3
\end{gather}

\begin{suspendequations}
A derivation
\begin{align}
a&=b\\
c&=d\\
e&=f
\end{align}
\end{suspendequations}

Now some text again
\begin{equation}
4
\end{equation}
Some other text
\begin{equation}
5
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This temporarily uses another counter within `equation`, which is started at the value of zero.

A LaTeX counter named `foo` is stored in a `\c@foo` macro, so instead of using `\c@equation` let the equation act on `\c@tempeq` for a while and change back later on.

Please note, that this might provide wrong labels and references and will confuse `hyperref` most likely -- I cannot recommend this really!

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{tempeq}



\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\end{equation}
\makeatletter
\let\origeq\c@equation
\let\c@equation\c@tempeq
\makeatother
\begin{equation}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\end{equation}
% Switch back the scheme
\makeatletter
\let\c@equation\origeq
\makeatother
\begin{equation}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```

Another option: Store the value of `equation`, reset the counter and store back at the end of `equation`. (or align)